# How to call a class method on a property of that class

Tags: c#, class-design

I am trying to figure out how to call a class method on a property of that class. Here are my two classes:

```
public class MrBase
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    public String NullIfEmpty()
    {
        if (this.ToString().Trim().Equals(String.Empty))
            return null;
        return this.ToString().Trim();
    }
}

public class MrResult : MrBase
{
    public String Owner { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }

    public MrResult() {}
}
```

MrResult inherits from MrBase.

Now, I want to be able to call the NullIfEmpty method on any of the properties of these classes... like so:

```
MrResult r = new MrResult();
r.Description = "";
r.Description.NullIfEmpty();
r.Owner = "Eric";
r.Owner.NullIfEmpty();
```

Thanks.

Eric

Comment: `Owner` is a string. You should call `r.NullIfEmpty()` instead.

Comment: Why not just create an extension method for this purpose?

Comment: Or you could use extension methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: Are you wanting it to mutate the property directly?  Or return a null if empty?

Comment: *Class methods* is a term that is also used on methods with C#'s `static` modifier (which means they're bound to the class itself rather than to an instance). Remember not to mix these things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write an extension method for `string`:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string NullIfEmpty(this string theString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(theString))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return theString;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string modifiedString = r.Description.NullIfEmpty();
```

If your main goal is to automatically "modify" each `string` property of your classes, you can achieve this using reflection. Here's a basic example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MrResult r = new MrResult
    {
        Owner = string.Empty,
        Description = string.Empty
    };

    foreach (var property in r.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property.CanWrite)
        {
            string propertyValueAsString = (string)property.GetValue(r, null);
            property.SetValue(r, propertyValueAsString.NullIfEmpty(), null);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I'd answer the very same thing. However, mind that you can `NullIfEmpty` on *any string* then, not just on `MrBase`'s properties.

Comment: @Mudu the extension is probably generic enough that it could be useful elsewhere.

Comment: And you can limit the Extensions class to internal in the same namespace as MrBase.

Comment: @Mudu See my answer, I have proposed a solution which is built-in to the class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want this code to be specific to your model, then you could built it into your setters with a slight modification to your `NullIfEmpty` method e.g.

```
private String _owner;

public String Owner
{
    get { return _owner; }
    set { _owner = NullIfEmpty(value); } 
}

...
public String NullIfEmpty(string str) 
{
    return str == String.Empty ? null : str;
}
```

Comment: +1 appears to make the interface safer, as the consumer is not required to invoke `NullIfEmpty` every time (seems to be done anyway I think, is it?).

Comment: Note that this won't trim the strings, or treat `" "` the same as `""`, as the asker's example code will.  You might need to modify appropriately.  I'd recommend looking at `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` instead of trimming and then checking if it's empty.

Comment: @Mudu yes it would be automatically called on the value as the property is set. Only downside is you would need to implement the same getter on every property. However, unless the OP wants to use reflection I can't really see anyway around this.

Comment: @TimS. a string with `" "` isn't an empty string. This solution delivers what the OP has asked for. If the OP wants to be more specific about whether they want to also treat whitespace as an empty string then I can update the solution...

Comment: James, thank you for this. However, I can not use this since there are times when I want to allow empty strings.

Comment: @Eric - could you be more specific, do you want to allow empty strings on different properties (if so simply omit the call from the setter). Or do you mean you want to have different instances of the class which can on some occassions allow an empty string?

Comment: The second option.... I want to have different instances of the class which can on some occassions allow an empty string.